# accessing bidimensional newListArray in Haskell

Tags: haskell

The following Haskell code is compiled with no errors or warnings:

```
import Control.Monad.ST
omport Data.Array.ST

nLA :: (Ix i) => (i,i) -> [e] -> ST s ((STArray s) i e) 
nLA = newListArray 

bs :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] 
bs xs = runST $ 
         do { xa <- nLA ((1,n),(1,n)) xs; 
              readArray xa (1,1); 
              getElems xa} 
         where n = length xs
```

but GHCi complains when the input to function `bs` is

```
bs [((1,1),1),((1,2),2),((2,1),3),((2,2),4)]
*** Exception: Error in array index
```

or the input

```
bs [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)]
*** Exception: Error in array index
```

So, what is the correct way to access the values from the array `xa`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first argument to `newListArray` you need to provide lowest and highest index in array. In your code you are providing `((1,n),(1,n))`. This means that lowest and highest indices are equal to `(1,n)`. Hence the result will be single-element array. And the index of that element will be `(1,n)`.

The `Error in array index` is because you are trying to read element at index `(1,1)` but there is no such element in array.

Your code will run without errors if `(1,n)` equals `(1,1)`. This will be the case only for single element `xs` (try `bs [123]`).

If you really want two-dimensional array, you need to provide sizes of both dimensions. E.g.:

```
bs m n xs = runST $ nLa ((1,1), (m,n)) xs >>= getElems
```

But in this case you need `xs` to be of length m*n to fill that array.

---

Btw, please don't use curly braces and semicolons in Haskell:

```
bs :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] 
bs xs = runST $ do
    let n = length xs
    xa <- nLA ((1,n),(1,n)) xs 
    readArray xa (1,1)
    getElems xa
```

Comment: Thank you so much. About the semicolons and brackets you're right, it looks like I am trying to embed C into Haskell

Answer (score 3):

`xa <- nLA ((1,n),(1,n)) xs` creates an array with one element, since the lowest and highest indices are both `(1,n)`. Of course, `readArray xa (1, 1)` fails on your examples because  the `(1,1)` index isn't in the arrays. `nLA ((1,1),(1,n)) xs` makes more sense in this context.